# Can't link CSS to HTML in Eclipse Java project

Tags: html, css, eclipse

I am building a web project at Eclipse in Java. I wrote a simple HTML and CSS files but I can't see how to link them and I can't spot the problem.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/AdminOptionCss.css" >
```

My files are located here:

[image: the paths of the files:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to give a relative path of that css file , it means that :
your HTML's are in `html` folder , but your CSS's are not in `html` folder but your are trying to load them from `html` folder!

what you need to do is, go a step backward in directory by using `../` and continue pathing, something like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/AdminOptionCss.css" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/AdminOptionCss.css" >
```

> ../ help you to navigate out of html location path , and after go to css and so on

Answer (score 0):

Change your Eclipse view to "Navigator" to see the real file path and use a relative path, like `href="../css/AdminOptionCss.css"` in your link tag.